# Old speeding ticket in Florida

Tags: usa, florida, colorado, fines

I went to visit my mother 11 years ago and got a speeding ticket in Florida. Needless to say, I forgot about it the first few days and chanced it by heading home to the UK.

Now, I want to visit her in Colorado and think I may be about to get a big dose of Karma. I've not seen her for 5 years and don't want this surprise to be ruined by having her pick me up from jail because of a crazy fine with 11 years interest on it.

Who do I contact to find out if I'm up the creek without a paddle?

Comment: Do you know where in Florida you got the speeding ticket? You can usually check with the county clerk. TBF I don't think you're at risk in colorado (speeding is a state offence, not a federal/national one). You might want to avoid waving your drivers license about if you visit Florida though.

Comment: In some cases, failing to respond to a ticket can result in a bench warrant for your arrest. An attorney can find out for you whether you have a bench warrant.

Comment: Unless you commit a crime in Colorado, the police will be unaware of the Florida issue. For an ordinary speeding ticket (not drink driving, etc.) you can probably clear your record by paying the original fine plus a substantial penalty.

Comment: I thought perhaps a statute of limitations would help here, but [apparently not](http://legalbeagle.com/7292346-statute-limitations-traffic-violations.html).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you contact someone there to help you with the process before come to US.

In Florida, you may have several options to pay your traffic ticket, including:

- Online.
- By mail.
- By phone.
- In person.

Comment: Calling that dmv.org link "the online system" makes it sound like is an official government information source, but in fact it is a privately operated site with no official status.  Also it does not appear to describe any official way to search for pending tickets.  They sell a fee-based "ticket history check" service but I doubt that it will work for someone with an international driving license.

Comment: well... that is why I suggest the way to find someone there. Because there is no official website to do it.

Comment: I would suggest you make that clear in your answer.  Also, do you have evidence to suggest this site will actually do what it claims in the OP's case, and help solve the problem?  I am skeptical.

Comment: That site tries to charge people money, and since it's entirely unofficial, you have no idea if a negative result there is at all meaningful or whether they don't have data from that location at all. I'd simply call the court clerk for free (or perhaps a few cents if you call internationally through a VoIP service) and ask. Sending someone to that site is just encouraging them to throw away their money.